# C# enabled для табов?

Tags: c#

Добрый день!
Возможно ли как-то отключить один таб из нескольких в C# и как это реализовать?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Покоретнее немного - WinForms или WPF? Какой класс контрола интересует?

Comment: WinForms. TabConrol.
Если я что не так ответил, простите, первый день на шарпе...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У TabPage нельзя установить свойство Enabled, с тем же результатом, что и для обычного контрола, но можно запретить переход на тот, или иной таб в TabControl:

```
private void tabControl1_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.TabPage == tabPage2) 
         e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для TabControl'а не получиться отключить одну из TabPage, точнее говоря у TabPage есть свойство Enabled, но вот что про него написано:

> Этот элемент не имеет смысла для данного элемента управления.

Есть два выхода:

1. Простой: вместо отключения таба нужно его удалять из табконтрола
2. Сложный: сделать контрол OwnerDrawFixed и самостоятельно рисовать и тогда можно будет сделать ему состояние "отключено" и визуально его сделать сереньким.

Comment: Спасибо. Видимо все-таки имеет смысл... :)

Comment: Рад помочь :) в русском MSDN иногда забавные перлы проскакивают...